# Quick load of AVFoundation video session

Tags: ios, performance, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I've encountered a very interesting example, that I am so curios to reproduce.
There is a great app that I love a lot using:
https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/oldbooth/id298007500?mt=8

I an not advertising as I am not the author.
Now they have a interesting point, when from a table view, by selecting a thumb, a ViewController with a video session is loaded.
What I've noticed:

1) The loading of the video session screen is really fast, almost no waiting.

2) No UIImagePicker shutter animation present

3) The VC appearance animations looks like "pushVC", I mean it is horizontal

4)the view with preview is firstly white, then with an alpha animation it goes to 0 alpha.

I have some experience using AVFoundation video capturing, but it is not as quick! It is incredible for me, and I see that this level of speed is possible, ofcourse I want the same.. Please could you please advice how it is possible to achieve such level of performance?

I am trying the following:

In parent VC, in didLoad:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.photoVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PhotoCreationVC"];

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{    
        [self.photoVC configureFoundation];
    });
```

The method does the following:

```
-(void) configureFoundation{
    NSError * error;
    _captureManager = [[AVCamDemoCaptureManager alloc] init];
    if ([_captureManager setupSessionWithPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh error:&error]) {
        [self setCaptureManager:_captureManager];
        _sessionEstablished = YES;
    } else {
        [Utils showMessage:[error localizedDescription] withTitle:@"Input Device Init Failed"];
    }

}
```

and when the VC runs didLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (_sessionEstablished) {
        AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:[_captureManager session]];
        UIView *view = self.previewView;
        CALayer *viewLayer = view.layer;
        CGRect bounds = view.bounds;

        [captureVideoPreviewLayer setFrame:bounds];

        if ([captureVideoPreviewLayer isOrientationSupported]) {
            [captureVideoPreviewLayer setOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
        }

        [captureVideoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

        self.captureVideoPreviewLayer = captureVideoPreviewLayer;


        if ([[_captureManager session] isRunning]) {

            [_captureManager setDelegate:self];

            NSUInteger cameraCount = [_captureManager cameraCount];
            if (cameraCount < 1) {
            } else if (cameraCount < 2) {
            }

            if (cameraCount < 1) {

            }

            [viewLayer insertSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer below:[[viewLayer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0]];


        } else {
            [Utils showMessage:@"Failed to start session." withTitle:@"Error"];
        }


    }

}
```

So what happens:
in the iTunes app it firstly loads the screen, then releases the alpha of the white view (i guess it is just cover view, which starts to lose alfa after a delay).
In my case, it still thinks a while before loading the VC. The time (1.5 seconds) is the same, but the waiting is not so friendly.

If i put all the loading code in didAppear, it loads immediately, but the loads, so the total time between tap and ready-video increases to 2.5 secs, which is not good.

If i put the loading code in willAppear, it works the same as in the first situation, when it first thinks, the loads (total 1.5 secs)...

PS I use AVCamDemoCaptureManager sample code from Apple, simplified, without any audio and movie output. just video input device and still image capturing.

Guys, please, can you give me some performance advice? how it is possible to achieve some high performance in loading a camera session? 
Any help will be highly appreciated!